# Backup all privileges related to specific user of MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to backup all privileges related to specific user (for example `u_1`) from a MySQL database and restore that in another server. As described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100516/119976), `The 'mysql' database contains users/privileges/passwords.` So I have to backup all related data from all tables of `mysql` database (`mysql.user`,`mysql.db`, ...). I can run this command:

```
$ mysqldump -u root --flush-privileges -r mysql.sql -p mysql
```

But of course the `mysql.sql` contains *all users and all privileges*.

Also I tried this command:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --where="user.user='u_1'" mysql user> mysql.sql
```

But as expected, it only contains a row of `mysql.user` table.

Is there a way to strip out other users except of `u_1`?

Comment: You don't like `grep`?

Comment: @JH It is in about `search`.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited to the dba forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these options (line breaks for clarity):

```bash
$ mysqldump -u root -p 
  --where="user='u_1'"
  --complete-insert
  --extended-insert
  --no-create-info
  mysql 
  user db tables_priv columns_priv procs_priv proxies_priv 
  > mysql.sql
```

Or... let's call the above solution "the hard way."

This should be the easy way:

```bash
$ mysql -u root -p
  --skip-column-names
  -e "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'u_1';"
  > grants.sql
```

Comment: The result of first way is: `Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `db` WHERE user.user='u_1'': Unknown column 'user.user' in 'where clause' (1054)
`

Comment: Sorry, that should say `--where="user='u_1'"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
pt-show-grants --only u_1
```

pt-show-grants is a tool in the free Percona Toolkit.

See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html